# Ajax : Custom style will disappear after ajax call is reloaded to table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, d3.js

I am creating custom style on Arcadia data (BI Tool) . I notice that after i tried to expand my table column or goes to page 2 on a table,it will revert back to its original stylesheet and my custom js will stop functioning.

For an example , i have 3 tables in a page

```
<div>
.. table 1 ..
</div>
<div>
table 2 ..
</div>
<div>
table 3 ..
</div>
```

once page is loaded,all custom styles/js stop firing . In a scenario where table 2 consist of 10 page, 10 data loaded per page. once i click on the next page, when data is loaded , my js stop.

ive tried document.ready , preventDefault. All attempts failed to launch fire js after data is loaded. when table is first loaded, it will appear the text "test" on each column. The problem starts when data is reloaded without having the page refresh ,it will bounce back to its original layout .

```
f.afterDraw = function () {
 const evt = d3.selectAll("#" + arcapi.chartId() + " span.crosstab-expand")
 const chChange = d3.selectAll("#" + arcapi.chartId() + " td.viz-td- header").append('div').attr('class','roger').text("test")



$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
           // chChange.style('background','red')
          let b = d3.selectAll("#" + arcapi.chartId() + " td.viz-td- header").append('div').attr('class','roger').text("test")
            console.log('data fired')
          });


 };
```

Next i did a .ajaxComplete.
console.log is firing on my log but its not retaining the div that i have appended to my table after data is reloaded.

Solution 2 i tried was using document.ready , log is firing but dom structure is going back to its own original style which does not has the div i added

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $("#" + arcapi.chartId()).on('click',function(){
            const chg = d3.selectAll("#" + arcapi.chartId() + " td.viz-td-header").append('div').attr('class','roger').text("test after change")
            console.log("call")
          });
```

how do i retain the text after ajax is reloaded?

Update :

```
f.afterDraw = function () {
     const evt = d3.selectAll("#" + arcapi.chartId() + " span.crosstab-expand")
     const chChange = d3.selectAll("#" + arcapi.chartId() + " td.viz-td-header").append('div').attr('class','roger').text("test")


    let bg = d3.select("#" + arcapi.chartId())


  $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    console.log('starting')
  });

  $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
     bg.style('background','grey')
    console.log('completed')
  });
  };
```

I tried applying custom color when ajax is completed. it is able to change background color. once ive appended to the table cell, it will revert back .