# Retain css after ajax is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

how to forcefully retain your css after ajax is completed, refreshed on table. currently it is going back to default css style.im trying to force td color grey, Any advice?

```
function chgColor(){
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
        bg1 = d3.select('table td')
        bg1.style('background','grey')
        console.log('completed')
      });
}
```

i have already tried many ways such as on pageinit but all has failed, it will only load on the first page loadup but after table is refreshed, it go back to its original styling

Comment: How often do you want to ask the same question ([first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60182115/ajax-custom-style-will-disappear-after-ajax-call-is-reloaded-to-table), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60182797/stop-loading-default-css-after-ajax-call), third/this)

Comment: it would be much easier to use `.addClass()` instead and add the custom styling in CSS files

Answer (score 0):

Is using a css rule outside of your AJAX container an option?

```
<style>
    table td.low { background-color: red; }
    table td.normal { background-color: green; }
</style>

<div id="ajaxContainer">
    this content will be replaced
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="low">1</td>
            <td class="normal">5</td>
            <td class="low">2</td>
            <td class="normal">7</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

this will always apply, unless some more specific rules override the rule.

Comment: i cant apply on style as i have conditions if a < 4 color red and so on, everytime table is reloaded or refresh, all css will disappear

Comment: i updated my answer to help with this issue. the idea is still the same: you would annotate your data table with classes and then provide styling for the classes outside. if you cannot add the classes when generating the table, you can also add them in your ajaxComplete with addClass.